# Can we intercept web API request and modify it based on certain constraint?

Tags: java, web-services, jackson, jax-rs, resteasy

I am using resteasy web services(Jackson) approach.

In my case `org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher` intercepts every web service request , is it possible to change web service  selection logic.

I don't want to do it using `Filters`.

Comment: How about looking at Camel?

Comment: I found a way to do it through ContainerRequestFilter where I can intercept every web API request and modify request URI on certain constraints.